# Convert a text to integer, increment and reconvert as text, any easier way?

Tags: java, android

I am doing a test android app, and even with some experience in C++, I m beginner in java.

I have a variable I m printing in a textArea, which count the number of push notification received. I successfully got a way to start a code at the receiving event, and want to increment it.

The way I found (which don t work) is to get the content of the textArea, convert it to integer, increment, convert to string, then to char[], and send back to the text area.

Class ParseStarterProjectActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    char [] test = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString()) + 1).toCharArray();

    System.out.println(test);

    textView.setText(test, 0, 10);
}
```

Class ParseApplication:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, Parse_ID, Parse_ID_2);

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, ParseStarterProjectActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

As it, the application crash, and logCat tell me (test still have the good value if I comment out setText):

```
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0, 10
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0, 10
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3572)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity.onCreate(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:24)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-24 13:00:43.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Why not use `setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString()) + 1))` ?

Comment: @Zouzou: because setText(String) doesn t exist.

Comment: `setText(CharSequence s)` exists and a `String` is a `CharSequence`

Comment: `then to char[]` why? you don't need that.

Comment: @Zouzou: you re right, I just forgot to link setText to textView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textView.setText(test, 0, 10);`

cause **IndexOutOfBoundsException** because your `char [] test` doesn't have length of 10.
So check the **length of char [] test** before trying to set it to TextView.

Something like,

```
if(test.length >= 10)
{
  textView.setText(test, 0, 10);
}else
{
  textView.setText(test, 0, test.length);
}
```

Comment: `textView.setText(test, 0, test.length);` is enought, I didn t understood it was supposed to be the size of the char[] I was supposed to give.

Comment: @DrakaSAN - I have just mentioned because of your question contains value 10. As I thought you have to use it length 10. If its not necessary then you can skip that part.

Comment: And As per your comment if you don't concern about `length of char[] test` then there is no need of converting String to char[] just dirct use of `int` with append `operator ""`.

Answer (score 1):

Store that number in class variable and show that variable value in `TextView`

```
private int count = 0;

//when needed update count
count++;

//show value in TextView
private void showValue() {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand where you are stuck, you want something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i = Integer.parseInt("100");
    i++;
    String v = String.valueOf(i);
    System.out.println("v = " + v);
}
```

Output is

```
v = 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

First, when you get text, better to put in local string.

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

String test = textView.getText().toString();
```

Second, when you want an int value, better surround it with try and catch for your safety.
Get the value like this:

```
int value;
    try {
         value = Integer.valueOf(test);
         value++;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        value = 1;
    }
```

Third, set the new number and log like this:

```
System.out.println("Current value: "+value);

textView.setText(String.valueOf(test));
```

hope it helps.